# What do you say when something is possible to parse or process?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When you want to process or parse something and you say it can be done, how do you say that the right way? Is it parsable, pars**e**able, or processable? Which is right? I can't find any of them in dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though my spell checker is giving me a red squiggly line even as I type, the OED lists *parsable* as a word, meaning "able to be parsed," with a reference stretching back into the late 1800s.

> 1889   Amer. Ann. Deaf & Dumb Apr. 105   *A sentence or
>   phrase‥perfectly parsable*.

Interestingly enough, though the OED lists four sample uses, none of them reference computer languages, which surprised me.

The OED does mention a more widely-used alternative word: *analyzable.*

*Processable* also gets listed as well, and my spell-checker is having no problem with that word.

So, you could use *analyzable* if you don't want to wave any red flags, *processable* if you want to look smart, and *parsable* if you want to appear erudite.    :^)

On a more serious note, [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/parsable) also lists both words, with a fairly large handful of sample sentences for both.

Comment: Funny though that neither the OALD nor its American version list anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

Both are used. "Parsable" is preferred in formal writing according to 
[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parsable#English).

Answer (score 2):

***Parseable*** strikes a hit also [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Parseable), whereas TheFreeDictionary.com does not recognize the other spelling.